# Transfer ownership of a Google My Business page without account access

Tags: google-plus-pages

How can I transfer ownership of a Google My Business page without knowing what account they are linked to?  We have acquired companies and have no access to the Google accounts.

Answer (score 1):

From https://support.google.com/business/answer/4661508?hl=en

> ## Resolve owner conflicts
>
> Each location on Google can have only one verified owner. If you see
> the status "Different owner" in your account, this means another owner
> has verified this location on Google.
>
> When you add a location that matches a live location with a different
> owner, it is treated as a duplicate and will be ignored when importing
> your spreadsheet.
>
> You have several options to address this issue:
>
> 1. **Check within your organization** to see who you may need to coordinate with, including agencies your company may have hired to
>    manage on behalf of the business. Learn more about [how to share
>    ownership of a set of
>    locations](https://support.google.com/business/answer/6085326).
> 2. **Request management** if you’d like to request a transfer of ownership from the current owner or to be added as a manager. [Learn
>    more](https://support.google.com/business/answer/4646651).
> 3. **Remove the location** from your account if you’d like the current owner to continue to manage the location. [Learn
>    more](https://support.google.com/business/answer/4669139).
> 4. **Leave the location in this state** if you only use it to run AdWords location extensions. [Learn
>    more](https://support.google.com/business/answer/6064538).
>
> If you claimed the location with a different account and have
> forgotten that account's username or password, [visit the Accounts
> troubleshooter](https://support.google.com/accounts/troubleshooter/2402620)
> to get help.